# How to display ListFragment in ActionBarActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, listactivity

I want to add [FileChooser](https://code.google.com/p/android-file-chooser/downloads/detail?name=File%20Chooser-src%20%282%29.zip&can=2&q=)(← I use this) to my app(my Main Activity extends ActionBarActivity).And I tried to change FileChooser to Fragment or ListFragment.
Because I want pages can be selected by user(I use drawer to select Fragment).

My app's structure like the picture:[enter link description here](https://imageshack.com/i/kq8YwtRLj)(because i can't post pictuer here)

But if I change to Fragment it didn't work.
If I change to ListFragment it will work ,but It displayed over last fragment like the picture:it beside the picture of above(please click the link again,because i can't post so many link)

> AndroidManifest.xml:
>   android:minSdkVersion="11"
>   android:targetSdkVersion="21"

My selectitem() code:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {        
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"case 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new First();
        break;
    case 1:            
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"case 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        fragment = new Second();
        break;          
    case 2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"case 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         fragment = new Third();
         break;        
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

My question:

1. How to change FileChooser from ListActivity to Fragment or ListFragment?(If someone has other methods, please tell me)
2. How can I display it after user click button(in First's layout) and will not see last Fragment's layout? 
   (if it can change to Fragment or ListFragment)
3. continue2 , How to Transfer data  to other fragments?
4. Which is better to import (in ActionBarActivity)?  (android.app.Fragment  or android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Thanks for everyone who read my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from bottom to top.

> Which is better to import (in ActionBarActivity)?
>   (android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Answer: Neither. It depends on what your doing and the API level you wish to conform with. I tend to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment more than the standard android.app.fragment but that's just preference more than anything.

> How can I display it after user click button(in First's layout) and
>   will not see last Fragment's layout? (if it can change to Fragment or
>   ListFragment) continue2 , How to Transfer data to other fragments?

Answer: A listfragment is a type of a fragment with a few extra methods. To replace a standard fragment with a listfragment you'll do the same thing.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction;

ft.replace(containerId, new MyListFragment or Fragment)
                         .commit();
```

As per moving data between fragments, the simplest way is to use a Bundle.

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putInt("myInt", 1);
data.putString("myString" "hello java")
myFragment.setArguments(data);
```

and in your Fragment class you'll get the data out of the bundle like this.

```
Bundle data = getArguments();
int myInt = data.getInt("myInt");
String myString = data.getString("myString");
```

and

> How to change FileChooser from ListActivity to Fragment or
>   ListFragment?(If someone has other methods, please tell me)

Are you looking at implementing the FileChooser class in a Fragment class or what exactly are you trying to say by this?

My selectFragment method would look like this:

```
public Fragment getFragment(int pos){
    switch(pos) {
        case 1:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case 3:
            return new FragmentThree();
        default:
            return FragmentOne();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it when I have free time.

Comment: No problem. If you can't make sense of it / get it working, let me know.